# Extracting images from database to website using php

Tags: php, database

I have images in my database in form of blob , what Im trying to do is that when I write in <input type="text" the name of the person in data base , picture of that person appears. It would be a blessing if someone helped

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the BLOB data is stored in the "image" field of a db table known as products.

Then if you want to show the image of the record with id=123, you may :

```
<?php

$id=123;

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "usernamexxxx", "passwordxxxxxx", "DbName");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';

?>
```

Note: if the image is a png, then please change `image/jpeg` to `image/png`

**Additional note:**

So for your special case "Enter the name of the person", the php and html will be like this (assuming that the name of the person is stored in the data field known as "name"):

The PHP : **target.php**

```
<?php

$name=$_POST["searchname"];

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "usernamexxxx", "passwordxxxxxx", "DbName");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';

?>
```

and the HTML form will be like:

```
<form action=target.php method=POST> 
<input name="searchname">
<br><input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , its working which is awesome. But my main issue is making it into a "search machine" with <input type text> as I stated in the post. I would be eternally gratefull if you could also lend me a hand here.

Comment: Please see my revised answer (see the "Additonal Note" part)

Comment: Yeah I saw it , everything works as it should , thank you so much for help , Im really glad